# Best approach for syncing / caching content in mobile app with backend

Tags: realm, google-cloud-firestore, aws-appsync

We about to build a mobile app which displays static content made up of text, images and videos.  For what it’s worth, it’s a social enterprise in the field of mental health.

We want the content displayed in the app to be driven by a CMS, so that it is easy to collaborate and update the content without needing to release an app update.  Normally I would just set up something like Django and expose the content via some REST endpoints.

However we’re keen to build a really great offline app experience, so the app is going to need a cache of this content one way or another.

I’ve been looking at Realm, Firestore and AppSync which all seem brilliant in many ways, but I’m wondering whether they are overkill for something like this, as really what we need is just uni-directional sync, not the bi-directional magic they provide.  I’m also slightly nervous about using something that isn’t as mainstream as REST (we once built something using Parse.. before Facebook shut it down).

My question is therefore are there any simple, widely used, reliable technologies or design patterns which solve the problem of syncing a cloud CMS into a mobile app data store
?